# How do I use awk to match multiple variable patterns?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, matching

I want to use awk to match multiple variable patterns. Here is what I have so far:

```
match=`awk -v "$var1\|$var2\|$var3" 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="-"}
$2 ~ {print}' $file`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: suggestion: please add few input lines and expected output for that sample along with values stored in the various variables.. that would help add clarity to question and serve as test data for checking solutions...

Comment: When you edit the question, don't change it. The answer of @anubhava uses the `BEGIN` and `$2` from the original question, and now they are looking weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass 3 variable separately using awk `-v var1=val1` syntax and then use alternation inside the awk regex as this one:

```
match=$(awk -v v1="$var1" -v v2="$var2" -v v3="$var3" 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="-"}
$2 ~ v1 "|" v2 "|" v3' "$file")
```

Comment: That would fail given various possible values of the shell variables and we don't even know if the OP wants to do a regexp or string match since he used the ambiguous term "pattern" to describe the type of match he wants, nor do we know if he wants partial or full matches. There's obviously a chance this will do what he wants but there's a bigger chance it'll just work on some sample input and then fail later wit his real data. Setting `OFS` is doing nothing btw.